# the difference between prepositions and particles?

Tags: parts-of-speech

> While driving along, Shiro’s owner decided to stop for awhile and she ran away again.

Is *along*  and *away* prepositions or particle? I am confused

Answer (score 1):

> *While driving along, Shiro’s owner decided to stop for awhile and she*
>   *ran away again*.

No, "along" and "away" are not particles.

Particles are the only complements that can freely come between a verb and its direct object. For example:

[1] *She took the suitcase **down** ~ She took **down** the suitcase.*

[2] *He made his intentions **clear** ~ He made **clear** his intentions.*

Particles are mainly prepositions, as in [1], but one or two of them can also be adjectives, as in [2].

In your example "along" and "away" are simply intransitive prepositions functioning as complements of "driving" and "ran".

Answer (score 0):

"Particle" is a rather loosely defined concept in English. It includes words that don't fit into other categories. Some people include all prepositions as type of particle. Other people don't

The word "to" used in the infinitive ("to play") is usually called a particle, the words that form a phrasal verb are also often called particles (Eg the word "out" in "He put the fire out")

Similarly "Run away" is usually considered to be a phrasal verb, so the word "away" is acting as a particle. Likewise for the phrasal verb "Drive along"